# Why pop-up appears under the content?

Tags: html, css

I'm asking for your help, it took half a day to try, but it didn't work.

I have a popup window that doesn't appear on top of the content on the page, but under it.
How can I fix this?

[image: here what i have]

Also, can you please give me some advice about the text over the picture, maybe I did something wrong?

My code of single card:

```
<div class="card_cat">
    <div class="image">
        <img class="card_cat__image" src="{{ item.image.url }}" width="300" height="250" alt="" />
        <a href="{% url 'products_retail_by_category' slug=item.slug %}">
            <div class="card_cat_title">
                {{ item.title }}
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pop-up:

```
<div id="popup__cart" class="popup__cart">
    <div class="popup__cart__body">
        <div class="popup__cart__content">
            <a href="##" class="popup__cart__close">
                <i class="fas fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card_cat {
    position:relative;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.card_cat__image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    filter: brightness(95%);
    width: 275px;
    height: 275px;
}

.card_cat_title {
    position: absolute;
    width: 230px;
    height: 28px;
    left: 22.5px;
    top: 123.5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.popup__cart {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.popup__cart:target {
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
}

.popup__cart__body {
    min-height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    padding: 30px 10px;
}

.popup__cart__close {
    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:20px;
}

.popup__cart__content {
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
    max-width:800px;
    padding:30px;
    position:relative;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `.popup__cart { z-index: 2;}` ?

Comment: Thank you so much!
need to see my face now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `z-index:999;` in pop-up